# linux embedded programming method - network setting

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I might missing out something in the general concept because I searched and didn't find answer for that...
I'm writing a GUI application in embedded Linux, C language. I would like to allow the user to change the network setting:

- DHCP client mode - I have busybox with uDHCPc application on the file system.
- If DHCP disabled, then configure the IP, subnet, gateway.

I already found out that IP, subnet and gateway can be changed using ioctl on a socket.
The only way I found to activate uDHCPc from my application is by calling the function: system(...) for execute shell command and this way awkward just like running a shell sript which run ifconfig for get/set ip address.

What is the right/common way for run "script activity" (DHCP enable/disable; read/write system setting) from my C application in embedded linux?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy

Answer (score 0):

DHCP is a protocol that works over a network. It is implemented in user space programs such as uDHCPc. There is no kernel implementation and no way to use ioctls for that. the system() function will work, but it also spawns an intermediate shell. If you want better efficiency you can just use fork() and exec() yourself to invoke uDHCPc as a subprocess.

Comment: Is it efficient to wrap uDHCPc with my own process which will catch signal/message for changing its status (enable/disable) and exec() it? or it would be better to recompile uDHCPc (or any other implementation of DHCP client) and integrate the signal/message mechanism into the client? is there a difference between the methods?

Comment: Maybe it's better to run it under init with a different runlevel. Then you can just switch runlevels.